# How to show the required fields on the first access of a View?

Tags: model-view-controller, field, validation, required

I am using MVC 2.0 and I wonder know how to show my required fields on the view on first acess.

For example.. I have a page that I can register a person and also I have my fields:

- Name;
- Age;
- City;
- Country;
- Phone;

But, just "Name" and "Phone" fields are requireds. I alread have the validation in my server side, but, I want that when somebody load the page, the page shows the required fields.

For example:
 Name [Put_text_here_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_***] *

I have on my pages:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.soliInscricaoImobiliaria})%>

<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "*") %>
```

How do I do that?

Best regards,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not super user-friendly, and I'd look at putting it into a `@helper` block. But short of simply hard-coding an asterisk into the form...

```
@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.First(m => m.PropertyName == "Name").IsRequired ? "*" : "")
```

More information here:

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html